# Node process exit before writeStream ends

Tags: node.js, http, pipe

I have a nodejs program downloading a bunch of files from a server. The problem is the process exits before the files has been actually downloaded, so I get a corrupted file.

```
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(items[i].filename);
    var request = http.get(items[i].url, function (response) {
      console.log('got:', i);
      response.pipe(file);
    });
    request.on('end', function () {
      console.log('done with ' + filePath);
    });
}
```

But when the last request receive its response, the process exits. I never get the "done with" log .

Anyone has an idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: It's because of the asynchronicity of your code. Basically, you have exited the loop before the callback was triggered.

Comment: I know that, I tried with es6-promise and sync-request but with no success ...

Comment: Have you tried the code I provided in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're handling the asynchronicity incorrectly.

Try using a library called `async` and use it like this

```
async.eachSeries(items, function (item, callback) {
   var file = fs.createWriteStream(item.filename);
   var request = http.get(item.url, function (response) {
       response.pipe(file);
   });
   request.on('end', function () {
       console.log('done with ' + filePath);
       callback(null);
   });
}, function (err) {
    console.log('All done!');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it looks very good but I can't get it to do what I want. I think I'm missing something ...
In my main loop I add object to a `downloadQueue` array of objects and iterate through it with the `async.each()` methods, but the process still exits prematurely :/

Comment: Then I guess it's lies somewhere else in your code. You could check which part of the code exits before the callback is called

Comment: The thing is I never get the "All done!" log, it seems node does not wait for async to quit its process

Comment: Hmm strange. I've never get this behavior. But in my case, I'm really sure that no code returns before a callback is called.

Comment: Forget it, the problem was on the request, your code fixed the original issue. It works perfectly now, thanks to you !